# How to Change IMG using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to change the image using javascript only without changing anything on the html

here is the HTML

```
<td bgcolor="#2A2A1B" style="width: 128px;" valign="top">
    <img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_imgClanmark" src="../images/clan/clanmark20130211202115640.png" style="height:128px;width:128px;" />
</td>
```

now here is my js

```
var photo = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_imgClanmark');
var img = new Image();
img.addEventListener('load', myFunction, false);
img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/jztMCqb.png';
photo.src = img.src;
```

tried it and it wont work

also used this

```
function FirstPic()
{
    var pic1 = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_imgClanmark"); 
    if (pic1 == typeof('image')) return;
    pic1.src = "http://i.imgur.com/jztMCqb.png";
}
```

but then again I should add codes on html like

```
<img onload='FirstPic()' id='ContentPlaceHolder1_imgClanmark' src='http://i.imgur.com/jztMCqb.png' />
```

Can someone help me on this one?

---

I'm sorry I haven't updated this question
here is what I did

--

```
window.onload = function() {
  var photo = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_imgClanmark');
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'http://i1203.photobucket.com/albums/bb384/zendesigns/sfdfi/sfdfilogo_zps9302a288.gif';
  img.addEventListener('load', myFunction, false);
  function myFunction() {
   photo.src = img.src;
  }
}
```

--

Thanks [Stano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422309/stano)

Comment: Hello, just put that `photo.src = img.src;` into that `myFunction` and it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/kd2jF/1/

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you're waiting for the onload event if this is on first pageload ?

```
document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_imgClanmark').src = 'http://i.imgur.com/jztMCqb.png';
```

will change the source ?

**EDIT:**

On the other hand the image on this link : `http://i.imgur.com/jztMCqb.png` can not be hotlinked, and returns ***403 forbidden*** when you try to link to it, so that image will never show up no matter what you do!

Answer (score -1):

Simply change src:

```
    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_imgClanmark").attr("src","pass_here_new_image_source");
```

Comment: He doesn't seem to be using jQuery.